# How can I add an array name in the json data

Tags: javascript, json

I am getting the data like this

```
[
  { "id":1,
    "name":"john"
  },
  { "id":2,
    "name":"ram"
  }
]
```

I want to change the above data to below

```
 "array":
[
  { "id":1,
    "name":"john"
  },
  { "id":2,
    "name":"ram"
  }
]
```

Comment: this question does not belong on the angular tag... this is about  js and json and not a specific framework

Comment: I want to do this question using angular only how can we achieve the output like that in angular

Comment: angular is a framework on top of the JavaScript Language. This question belongs into JS syntax, it is not angular specific. My answer below would work for angular as well as  anything else using JS

Answer (score 1):

The way to format your object in JavaScript would be something like this:

```
{ 
  "array": [
    { "id":1, "name":"john" },
    { "id":2, "name":"ram" }
  ]
{
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to do this in angular, typescript.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get this statement `I want to do this question using angular only how can we achieve the output like that in angular` as it's all about structuring/wrapping the `JSON` data. Hence, I added the solution in `angular.js` snippet below.

**Demo (Angular) :**

```js
function ArrayController($scope) {
    const resData = [{
    "id":1,
    "name":"john"
    }, {
    "id":2,
    "name":"ram"
  }]; 
    $scope.data = {
    array: resData
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.1.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="ArrayController">
    <div>{{ data }}</div>
</div>
```